# Is there a datagrid for SharePoint web parts?

Tags: 2007, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

I have some background in WPF / C# and would like to replicate what I can do there with datagrids in a SharePoint web part. Is there an equivalent control that I could use? If not, what do people normally do when they would like to show a grid output of data from a database within a custom developed part?

Unfortunately a data view web part does not suit my purpose as it exposes the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint is built on top of ASP.NET Web Forms so any grid control you can use with Web Forms should also work in SharePoint. SharePoint also has it's own grid control, SPGridView, which inherits from the ASP.NET GridView control.

One important note, SharePoint 2007 is implemented on .NET 2.0 so if you're looking at third-party controls you'll need one that works with that version of the framework.